# Macbook pro internal HD not detected

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility, disk-format, hdd

I had a problem with my bootcamped MBP and I tried to format the HD. I wasn't able to format any of the partitions so I tried the following based on https://www.macissues.com/2014/04/05/how-to-fix-deep-formatting-problems-with-os-x-drives/:

```
cat /dev/random > /dev/disk0
```

Now, when I boot from a USB to try to re-format the disk and make a clean install of OSX, I do

```
diskutil list
```

But my /dev/disk0 is not showing up.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the drive because has no more partition on it.  What you have done is written every sector, including the super important ones like the partition table, with random numbers.

When you boot USB (I am assuming you are booting an OS X installer off of USB), you need to launch *Disk Utility*.  It will be under the "Tools" menu.  Partition your disk with GUID partition map and reinstall OS X.

Comment: When I open Disk Utility, the internal HD doesn't show up in the list!

Comment: Execute this command in Terminal and see if your drive shows up.  `system_profiler SPStorageDataType`